# Why there is no Seq.rev function?

Tags: f#

Looks like such a made up complication to me. In order to reverse a sequence (enumerable) one have to turn it to a list first. Why is that?

Comment: Sequences are lazy and can be infinite; reversing a sequence is almost always bad, and sometimes impossible.

Comment: Well, that's a poor argument, there is Seq.length that would be considered as bad.

Comment: Your point is right, it's not very clear to me the rationale behind that decision however I think the difference with Seq.length although both functions will fail over infinite sequences is that length can "throw away" the elements as it counts. The same applies to Seq.last and eventually to fold.

Comment: @gustavo, there is also Seq.sortBy that keeps elements

Comment: Yes, there is also group functions, as said before, not very clear at least to me what is the criteria.

Comment: F# 4.0 has `Seq.rev` (though I couldn't find it on MSDN yet) which, obviously, reverses a sequence. Be careful: don't use it on unlimited sequences.

Answer (score 6):

Since you can't walk through sequences backwards, lists are an ideal storage medium for reversing sequences.  They even have the tendency of becoming reversed as you build them, go figure.

I have no idea why `rev` isn't in the Seq module in the first place, though.  Even LINQ has a `Reverse()` operator.  Fortunately, it is very easy to implement.

```
let rev xs = Seq.fold (fun acc x -> x::acc) [] xs
```

Another alternative is to just use LINQ's operator.

```
let rev = System.Linq.Enumerable.Reverse
```

Comment: For anyone who finds this two-year-old answer, it's worth noting that F# 4 has filled in the "gaps" between List, Array and Seq so that they now have similar APIs. `Seq.rev` now exists, as do many other functions that were "missing" from Seq: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/ListSeqArrayAdditions.md

Answer (score 4):

Why is there no `rev` yet there are other functions that consume the entire sequence (`length`, `sortBy`, `groupBy`)? Fundamentally, why is *any* function a good choice for inclusion in the standard library? I'll hazard a guess that it's less a set of precise rules and more a matter of hitting a "sweet spot." For example, is it a good intersection of: useful, expected, performant, encourages good practice, ...a bit subjective (which is why this question is ultimately unanswerable) but practical, and in most cases intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

The API on which `Seq` is implemented has essentially two functions

1. Get the next item
2. Are we at the end of the list

As a result, there is no way to check the length of the list.  Enumeration can also be very expensive as there is no caching of results and might even cause side effects to occur.

Also, sequences may be infinite.

As a result, we don't have `Seq.rev`, and we need to use a transform to another sequence first.

Comment: How about Seq.length?

Comment: Or Seq.fold or Seq.last for the same matter? As for not caching the results, how does the Seq.sortBy work then?

Comment: @bonomo `Seq.length` goes over the whole sequence. It will never return for infinite (or pseudo-infinite) sequences.

Comment: @RamonSnir, I know that thank you, my point is Seq.lengh (as well as Seq.last, Seq.fold, etc) should not be included to the Seq module for the very same reason John said the Seq.rev didn't make it there.

Comment: "The API on which Seq is implemented has essentially two functions". The API also has "initialize sequence" before anything else and "dispose of sequence" after everything else. So a sequence can create a database connection to stream some results and then close it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

> Sequences are particularly useful when you have a large, ordered collection of data but do not necessarily expect to use all the elements. Individual sequence elements are computed only as required, so a sequence can provide better performance than a list in situations in which not all the elements are used
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233209.aspx

```
let rnd = System.Random()
let nums = seq {
    let rec getNext() = seq {
        yield rnd.Next(100)
        yield! getNext()
    }
    yield! getNext()
}

let len = nums |> Seq.length //nums is an infinite sequence, will not stop
```

Comment: Even simpler example `let t = Seq.initInfinite id`